# Natural treatment of chronic prostatitis - Does herbal medicines have side affects?‏

Tags: antibiotics, natural-remedy, diuretics, prostatitis

I have had prostatitis for several years. Since almost all antibiotics were not helpful to me due to drug resistance, I am trying to find some natural treatment of chronic prostatitis, so I Googled one diuretic and anti-inflammatory pill. How does it cure prostatitis? any successful cases? What are the side effects?

Comment: Every medication regardless of origin has side affects

Comment: Welcome to Health! This question seems to be asking for personal medical advice, which is [not considered on-topic on Health.SE](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/are-personal-medical-advice-questions-on-topic-here). If you can, please edit your question to remove the request for personal health advice. Thanks :)

Comment: As @Chris says, welcome to Health! I have taken your question as requesting information on the condition and side-effects in general, rather than in your specific case. That said, I hope you can find something that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

## Herbal medicines do have side effects

The answer to any *"does this have side-effects?"* question is  invariably *yes*.

Some drugs/medications/herbal remedies will have fewer side effects, some will have more. Additionally (or alternatively), the side effects may vary by strength, or by how common they are, or any a number of other ways.

I could not find any listing of ingredients or side effects for the example herbal medicine you mentioned.

## What about this diuretic and anti-inflammatory pill

I looked for your "one diuretic and anti-inflammatory pill", and found just that: a bunch of results about something literally named [Diuretic and Anti-inflammatory Pill](https://forums.netdoctor.co.uk/discussion/104945/natural-herbal-prostatitis-treatment-diuretic-and-anti-inflammatory-pill).

It claims to have at least three different effects<sup>*</sup>; frankly, it is hard to know what, if anything, it does without knowing what the ingredients are.

There is [a small Reddit discussion of the pill](https://www.reddit.com/r/Prostatitis/comments/6h0yw8/diuretic_and_antiinflammatory_pill/), which may be of interest.

### Why might not antibiotics 'cure' prostatitis?

Acute prostatitis is [often caused by E. coli](http://bestpractice.bmj.com/topics/en-gb/172), but chronic prostatitis is a bit different. Chronic prostatitis [can follow acute prostatitis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8886062), but [often it is abacterial](https://www.healthline.com/health/chronic-prostatitis#types)- as such, antibotics won't be effective.

(That would be [**Category III** prostatitis, in NIH categorisation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10422990), which overlaps with Chronic Pelvic Pain Syndrome (CPPS)).

## References

- [Acute prostatitis - Summary](http://bestpractice.bmj.com/topics/en-gb/172)
- [Chronic prostatitis: results of an Internet survey](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8886062)
- [Chronic prostatitis - Healthline](https://www.healthline.com/health/chronic-prostatitis#types)
- [Natural Herbal Prostatitis Treatment: Diuretic and Anti-inflammatory Pill](https://forums.netdoctor.co.uk/discussion/104945/natural-herbal-prostatitis-treatment-diuretic-and-anti-inflammatory-pill) (No endorsement implied by linking to this)
- [Diuretic and anti-inflammatory pill?? (Reddit)](https://www.reddit.com/r/Prostatitis/comments/6h0yw8/diuretic_and_antiinflammatory_pill/)
- [NIH consensus definition and classification of prostatitis.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10422990)

---

<sup>*</sup>: You can read the claims yourself, I don't wish to lend them any implied credence by reproducing them here.

Comment: Providing or looking for information on what "can" help when you have no ability to effectively diagnose the problem can be dangerous.  How do you know the problem is CPPS and not any other kind of Prostatitis?  Giving medical advice is frowned upon here for safety reasons

Comment: If you wish to provide a general answer without risk of giving what can be considered medical advice, I would just stick to the side effects risks just as you have, although again this can differ from person to person.  How medication works and what treatment paths **may** be required should be left to the OPs doctor who has the ability to effectively diagnose the problem and give the correct advice.  Giving something which **might** help could exacerbate the problem, and in extreme cases with some medical conditions it could lead to death.

Comment: I have removed that section. If you have any further suggestions or feel it could be improved further, please let me know.